# Read Only problems with shared Data Drive after Win 10 upgrade

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, windows, partitioning

Cannot access my data partition after updating windows.
I have Win 10, UbuntuMate, and a partition called Data on my machine to share between OS's.

I recently upgraded Win 10 and now I cannot access my Data drive with write permission on Linux OS's on my machine.

To test whether anything I did was successful, I right click in Caja and see if I can create a folder.. NOPE..it is grey

I have tried:

shift + shutdown (Usually works for c-drive r+w problems)

Changing permissions to full control in Windows

Changing sharing to everyone in Windows

I also tried this in term
 sudo chmod /media/bhante/Data -R -rwxrw-rw

and

sudo chmod /media/bhante/Data -R -rwxrw-rw a

it returns "read only file system" for all files:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/media/bhante/Data/yush/yushsign.com/index.html': Read-only file system
```

Below are the settings in "Disks" to automount
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not long ago, while in windows.. hitting SHIFT + SHUTDOWN menu item would completely shut down the computer.  It seems that the latest release (September) ignores this key-sequence and the drive is still "in exclusive use"

hit WINDOWSkey + R
type powercfg.cpl 
Click "Choose what the power buttons do" from the column on the left. 
scroll down and choose turn off fast boot.

You might have to click a button above that that says change settings not allowed.
Then you can uncheck fast boot.
See this link https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10